# Scrapy Downloading Files Error

Tags: error-handling, web-scraping, scrapy, http-status-code-301

I'm using the files pipeline in `Scrapy` to download subtitle files off of http://opensubtitles.org.

I've got a list of all the http://dl.opensubtitles.org links, and my spider follows these links and sends the urls to the pipeline.

It works to start, and I can download the first ~100 files without any issue.

However, around then the links seem to create the error:

> 2016-06-09 11:44:02 [scrapy] WARNING: File (code: 301): Error downloading file from http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/vrf-108d030f/sub/24617> referred in

Does it have something to do with my code?

These are in my settings:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1}

FILES_STORE = 'C:/Users/Rohan/Documents/Fitroom/subtitles/subFiles'
```

This is my pipeline:

```
class SubtitlesPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error maybe occurred due to download time out, because file maybe bigger in size. Increase download time out.
Try this in setting.py file

```
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 500
```